# Spring on Fargate can't connect to AWS SES

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send emails through my Java application that I'm running on a container in Fargate. My containers are running in a VPC behind a API gateway, the connections to external services are made through VPC endpoints.

All that infra is deployed using Terraform. The Java app runs ok localy, but not when deployed to AWS, so I'm thinking that there is one missing config.

The Java app follows the AWS guidelines found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-raw.html

Following are some spinets of the Terraform code:

```
# SECURITY GROUPS
resource "aws_security_group" "security_group_containers" {
  name   = "security_group_containers_${var.project_name}_${var.environment}"
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    protocol         = "-1"
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
    self             = true
  }

  egress {
    protocol         = "-1"
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "security_group_containers_${var.project_name}_${var.environment}"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "security_group_ses" {
  name        = "security_group_ses_${var.project_name}_${var.environment}"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id

  ingress {
    protocol    = "-1"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = "-1"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "security_group_ses_${var.project_name}_${var.environment}"
  }
}

# VPC

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
    cidr_block           = var.cidr
    enable_dns_support   = true
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
  }

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
    vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main.id
    cidr_block        = var.private_subnets[0]
    availability_zone = "us-east-1b"

    tags = {
        Name= "private_subnet_${var.project_name}_${var.environment}"
    }
}


# VPC ENDPOINT
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ses_endpoint" {
  security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.security_group_ses]
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.${var.aws_region}.email-smtp"
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  subnet_ids          = [aws_subnet.private_subnet.id]
  private_dns_enabled = true
  tags = {
    "Name" = "vpc_endpoint_ses_${var.project_name}_${var.environment}"
  }
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
}
```

If there are any important service missing tell me so I can add it.

As you can see I'm keeping all traffic open, so the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64989152/aws-fargate-not-sending-emails-from-private-subnet-with-ses-endpoint) doesn't works for me. When the app tries to send an email I get to following error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443 [email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/52.0.170.238, email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/54.234.96.52, email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/34.239.37.81, email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/18.208.125.60, email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/52.204.223.71, email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/18.235.72.5, email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/18.234.10.182, email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/44.194.249.132] failed: connect timed out
```

I think that I'm missing some config to make the java awssdk use the VPC endpoint.

Edit 01 - adding execution policies:

arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSESFullAccess

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ses:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonECS_FullAccess (too large)

arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit 02 - changed to use a SMTP library:

The code used can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-using-smtp-programmatically.html)

Everything worked fine with SMTP

Comment: My guess is that your Fargate execution role does not allow accessing SES: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_execution_IAM_role.html.

Comment: Added AmazonSESFullAccess permission, still get the same error

Comment: Can you add the execution policy to the question as well?

Comment: @MarkoE sure, just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a VPC endpoint for the SES SMTP API, but the error message you are getting `email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443` is for the AWS SES Service API. You can see the two sets of APIs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/ses.html). If you are using the AWS SDK to interact with SES in your Java application, then you need to change VPC endpoint to be `service_name = "com.amazonaws.${var.aws_region}.email"`

Your current endpoint configuration would work if you were configuring your Java application to use SMTP (such as with the JavaMail API).

Comment: Unfortunately: Error creating VPC Endpoint: InvalidServiceName: The Vpc Endpoint Service 'com.amazonaws.us-east-1.email' does not exist

Comment: @FelipeHogrefeBento sorry, apparently SES only supports the SMTP interface for VPC endpoints at this time. So you will have to switch from using the AWS SDK to interact with SES, to using an SMTP library.

Comment: Ok, by using a SMTP library the error changed, seems that it can't connect to port 587, let me add as an edit

Comment: Destroyed and deployed all the infra again and it worked using SMTP, thanks

Comment: This post should be updated to reflect the fact that the `email` VPC endpoint does not exist.